# Syntax for If Then SUMIFS

Tags: excel, vba

In the code below, I have identified a range (ColRng) in which I want to check each cell - if it is empty, there is a SUMIFS function to perform. It does not work. I know my syntax and logic is horrid, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
Dim ColRng As Range
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRowScenario As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim rngCrit1 As Range
Dim rngCrit2 As Range
Dim rngSum As Range

LastRowScenario = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q2").End(xlDown).Row

Set rngCrit1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & LastRowScenario)
Set rngCrit2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & LastRowScenario)
Set rngSum = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q2:Q" & LastRowScenario)

LastCol = Sheets("Summary").Range("B5").End(xlToRight).Column
Set ColRng = Range(LastCol & "6:" & LastCol & "149")

For x = ColRng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    With ColRng.Cells(x)
        ' If the cell is empty, perform a SUMIFS
         If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
  .Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rngSum, rngCrit1, .Range("E" & .Row).Value, rngCrit2, .Range("B" & .Row).Value)
        End If
    End With
Next x
```

Comment: what does it do that is incorrect?

Comment: The line with SUMIFS function throws an "application-defined or object-defined error". I do not know how to make this function apply to the cell that it being checked by the If then.

Comment: Remove all `ActiveCell`  and put `Application.` in front of the WorksheetFunction: `.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rngSum, rngCrit1, .Range("E" & .Row).Value, rngCriteria2, .Range("B" & .Row).Value)`  And this is assuming that the other variables are all correct as you did not include how they are declared or set.

Comment: Same error. Have edited original post to include my definitions.

Comment: remove the `.` in front of the `Range`s inside the SUMIFS.

Comment: It didn't give me the error, but it ran for two minutes before I force ended the macro. When it stopped, there were thousands of empty rows in the worksheet, so I'm guessing it's doing something outside of `ColRng`. My intention was for the IF/Then/Sumifs to run in `ColRng`, which is meant to be the last column on the right from rows 6 to 149

Comment: `.Column` returns a numeric column index, not a column letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ColRng` construction is wrong - try something like this instead:

```vb
Dim ColRng As Range
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRowScenario As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim rngCrit1 As Range
Dim rngCrit2 As Range
Dim rngSum As Range, ws As Worksheet, wsSumm As Worksheet

set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set rngSum = ws.Range("Q2:Q" & ws.Range("Q2").End(xlDown).Row)
Set rngCrit1 = rngSum.EntireRow.Columns("D")
Set rngCrit2 = rngSum.EntireRow.Columns("B")

Set wsSumm = Sheets("Summary")
With wsSumm.Range("B5").End(xlToRight).EntireColumn
    Set ColRng = wsSumm.Range(.Cells(6), .Cells(149))
End With

For x = ColRng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    With ColRng.Cells(x)
        ' If the cell is empty, perform a SUMIFS
         If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
             .Formula = Application.SumIfs(rngSum, _
                  rngCrit1, .EntireRow.columns("E").Value, _
                  rngCrit2, .EntireRow.columns("B").Value)
        End If
    End With
Next x
```

Comment: It's not summing anything. Just returns 0 values. Can I ask why you've included the `.EntireRow` for `rngCrit1` and `rngCrit2`? I'm looking in `ws` columns D and B for the values in `wsSumm` columns E and B.

Comment: `.EntireRow.Columns("E")` is Column E on the same row as `ColRng.Cells(x)`   Try (eg) `Degug.Print rngSum.Address()` to make sure your ranges are what you expect.

Comment: I figured it out. The values in `rngCrit2` had some extra values in the string following the text I was looking for. Should be able to wrap the `.EntireRow.columns("B").Value` in a `left` function and get what I need. Thanks!